# clearTimeout fails sporadically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to manage a timer in an Angular 2 environment, and clearTimeout seems to only work correctly about half the time. I am writing in TypeScript.

I keep the timer in its own service:

```
export class TimeoutService {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private httpService: HttpService
    ) {}

    //Properties
    private timer;

    //Methods
    public clearTimer() {
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }

    private logOut() {
        return this.httpService.Post('api/session/logout', '');
    }

    private redirectToTimeoutPage() {
        this.router.navigate(['/timeout']);
    }

    public refreshTimer() {
        console.log('refreshing timer');

        if (this.timer) {
            this.clearTimer();
            this.setTimer();
        }
    }

    public startTimer() {
        this.setTimer();
    }

    private setTimer() {
        this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
            this.logOut()
                .then(() => {
                    this.clearTimer();
                    this.redirectToTimeoutPage();
                });
        }, 30000);
    }
}
```

I know from the console.log in the refreshTimer method that it is being called when I expect it to be, and not otherwise. However, most of the time, earlier timers will not be canceled by the clearTimeout call, and will fire once their thirty seconds is up even though they should have been replaced by a new timer.

I've been through the other SO questions about this and none applies to my situation as far as I can see.

The one clue I've got, which I can't decipher, is that if I remove the call to `this.setTimer()` within refreshTimer, then the clearTimeout call seems to work fine. In other words, creating a new timer is somehow causing the old one to survive. What am I missing here?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you include some code to show your actual usage of the TimeoutService class?

Comment: Just as a best practice, I would advise you always initialize your variables. In the case of the timer (since you are checking for its existence later), I would initialize it to `null` (i.e. `private timer = null;`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `refreshTimer` you take care of calling `this.clearTimer()` before calling `this.setTimer()`.

However, in `startTimer`, you do not call `this.clearTimer()`. So if the calling code calls `startTimer` more than once without doing anything that calls `this.clearTimer` in between, you're going to start multiple timeouts, but **only the last one will be remembered by your class and cancelled** when `this.clearTimer` is called again.

Comment: Got it in one! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

In your `clearTimeout` function, you not only want to clear the timer, but you also want to reset your `timer` variable:

```
public clearTimer() {
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
    this.timer = null; // <-- You also want your variable to become null here.
}
```

Then, any code that runs after a call to `clearTimer()` will correctly evaluate the `timer` variable as `null` which correctly indicates that no timer exists. Simply stopping the running timer isn't enough for your wrapper.

Also (FYI), as I said in the comments, it's a very good best-practice to initialize all your variables so no "surprise" values appear out of no where.

```
 private timer;
```

Should be:

```
 private timer = null;
```

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts, I've integrated them into the code as best practices.

Answer (score 1):

I would move the call to `clearTimer` into the `setTimer` function and see if that helps.